# PHP Parse an arrays values to a function

Tags: php, arrays

Ok so I have a function with 2 mandatory arguments and then it must have many optional arguments too.

```
function example($a,$b, $username, $email) {
    // code
}
```

My data for the optional arguments comes from an array

```
$x = array('joeblogs', 'joe@blogs.com');
```

How would i be able to parse these? bearing in mind that the function may be required to parse  a different set of arguments each time.

An example is with CakePHP you can specify the action arguments that are required

Answer (score 5):

Something like this?

```
$a = 'a';
$b = 'b';
$x = array('joeblogs', 'joe@blogs.com');

$args = array_merge(array($a, $b), $x);

call_user_func_array('example', $args);
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches to optional arguments.

In the first, you specify all of the arguments like this:

```
function example($a, $b, $c=null, $d=null, $e=null)
```

Parameters `$a` and `$b` are required. The others are optional and are `null` if nothing is provided. This method requires that each of the optional parameters be specified in the indicated order. If you want to call the method using only `$a`, `$b` and `$e` you have to provide null values for `$c` and `$d`:

```
example($a, $b, null, null, $d);
```

The second method accepts an array as the third parameter. This array will be checked for keys and processed based on the keys found:

```
function example($a, $b, $c=array()) {

    $optionalParam1 = ( !empty( $c['param1'] ) ) : $c['param1'] ? null;
    $optionalParam2 = ( !empty( $c['param2'] ) ) : $c['param2'] ? null;
```

In this way, you can check for each key that may be provided. Null values will be provided for any key not populated.

Answer (score 0):

Following shows syntax for optional parameters and default values

```
function example($a,$b, $username = '', $email = '') {

}
```

Another possibility is to pass an "optional values array"

```
function example($a,$b, $optional_values = array()) {
    if($optional_values[0] != '') { blah blah .... }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is a merge of your sugestion and Jez's solution.

```
call_user_func_array(array($controller, $action), $getVars);
```

Where `$controller` is the instance of your controller, `$action` is the string to the action that you want to call, and `$getVars` is an array of parameters.

The first parameter of the `call_user_func_array` function is a callback. It's possible to define a method invocation as callback.

Here is a link to the documentation of PHP's callback: http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback

Answer (score 0):

To pass the array parameters to a function you can use [call_user_func_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php):

```
$args = array( 'foo', 'bar', 'joeblogs', 'joe@blogs.com' );
call_user_func_array( 'example', $args );
```

Or simple pass any number of parameters:

```
example( $a, $b, $username, $email );
```

To retrieve the parameters inside function use [func_get_args](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php):

```
function example() {
    $args = func_get_args();

    print_r( $args );

    // output:
    //  Array ( 
    //      [0] => foo 
    //      [1] => bar 
    //      [2] => joeblogs 
    //      [3] => joe@blogs.com 
    //  )

}
```